# SASS indented syntax on multiple lines?

Tags: css, sass

I love Sass's [indented syntax](http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.INDENTED_SYNTAX.html) (as opposed to SCSS, which is whitespace agnostic and uses brackets and semicolons). I think it's much cleaner.

There's one issue I have with it. If I have a really long line, there's no way to split it into multiple lines (obeying the 80 character limit, for example)

Take this example of a really long mixin declaration, first written in SCSS.

```
@mixin col($cols, $mleft: 0, $mright: 0, $include-margin: false, $border: 0,
           $pleft: 0, $pright: 0, $include-padding: true, $extra: 0, 
           $clear: false, $lead: true, $container: false) {
    color: red;
    display: block;
}
```

I'm able to split up one long declaration in to multiple lines. With the indented syntax, I don't think there's a way. I have to put the declaration on one line, which is way less readable.

```
@mixin col($cols, $mleft: 0, $mright: 0, $include-margin: false, $border: 0, $pleft: 0, $pright: 0, $include-padding: true, $extra: 0, $clear: false, $lead: true, $container: false)
    color: red
    display: block
```

Is there some way I don't know of? :(

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2389797/is-there-a-multiline-in-sass is marked as a duplicate, but it has a better answer. To summarize: there's no multiline in Sass, there is multiline in SCSS though. See also https://github.com/sass/sass/issues/216.

Answer (score 6):

Multiline is not supported by sass. Reading the doc, there is one exception, when it comes to multiple css selectors like in this example:

```
.users #userTab,
.posts #postTab
  width: 100px
  height: 30px
```

Read the doc here: http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.INDENTED_SYNTAX.html#multiline_selectors

So, sadly: There is no possibility to get multi-line support for an argument list in sass.

Comment: users coming from [stylus](http://stylus-lang.com/) beware: unlike stylus, line 1 does need a trailing comma, otherwise you get silent failure (aka: a useless line)

Answer (score 5):

*First: do not create mixins with so many arguments. Divide it to many small mixins or insert some similar arguments as arrays (Sass have data maps for it).*

Second: you can use temporary variables just for readability of your large code.

For example:

```
=mixin($argument)
    body::before
        content: $argument
$v1: 'foo-'
$v2: 'bar-'
$v3: 'baz.'
$var: $v1+$v2+$v3
+mixin($var)
```

This will get you mixin with all your `$v#` strings joined to one `$var`.

```
body::before {
    content: 'foo-bar-baz';
}
```

If someone knows better way to join many strings into one in indented Sass syntax, I will be happy to know. Because I write complex gradients and inline generated SVG with this.

Comment: This answer really deserves more the zero upvates! 

In general, if lines get too long, just storing parts of it into variables with help.