# Make sass prettier

Tags: sass, whitespace

i'm just trying to make my sass a little more readable. I have some mixins with a lot of arguments and I would usually like to be able to white space them a little more. This is a very small example:

```
+color ("bg-" "txt-", "background-color" "color", $all_colors )
```

I would like to make into

```
+color (
  "bg-" "txt-",
  "background-color" "color",
  $all_colors )
```

or somethine like that. any ideas?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sass indented syntax on multiple lines?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8248976/sass-indented-syntax-on-multiple-lines)

Comment: Currently, [sass doesn't support multiline expressions](https://github.com/nex3/sass/issues/216) so it's not possible to achieve a more readable way to declare mixin arguments dividing them into different lines. Like link comments says Sass developers are working to implement this function